# Measure variation in a time series

Tags: time-series, variance, standard-deviation

I have a series of values, they are a time series. I know what standard deviation is. I want to measure how much values in a series differ from one value to the next.

```
50,50,50,50,50,100,100,100,100,100

50,100,50,100,50,100,50,100,50,100
```

This two series have the same standard deviation. I want to know is there some other measure that would measure how this two series are different. The series are made for better understanding of my point, they are not real numbers.

Comment: You could construct a linear model (maybe polynomial given your data) and look at the `R^2` (ratio explained variance) by the curve.

Comment: Did you ever find a measure that measures this?

Answer (score 1):

I come across a similar but much more complicated problem today. For the problem you posted, a way to measure the variation is to calculate the standard deviation of the two series' 1-step difference. i.e. you can compare the following two results:

```
std([0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0])=15.713
std([50,-50,50,-50,50,-50,50,-50,50])=49.690
```